# Multiple IPs on different subnets on one interface

Tags: networking, ip

I have managed to configure two IPs from different subnets on the same card. I changed /etc/network/interfaces to have:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 172.16.4.254
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.16.4.0
    broadcast 172.16.4.255
    gateway 172.16.4.1
    dns-nameservers 172.16.4.1

iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The problem is that the connections over the first IP started being laggy (the response time increased greatly). For instance it takes a lot of time to start loading a webpage, but it does eventually succeed. I need a console/configuration solution. No gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not configure `eth` on that way.
Create aliases

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address 192.168.10.11
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
```

Comment: Creating _aliases_ is considered _legacy_ ... the OP way is correct: https://askubuntu.com/questions/547289/how-can-i-from-cli-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-interface but some network cards struggle with it.

Comment: Is this for physical adapters or virtual adapter IP's ?
How should be configured the file in both cases ?