# How can I (from CLI) assign multiple IP addresses to one interface?

Tags: networking, command-line, ip-address

On my server I want to assign several IP addresses to one NIC, but without using the deprecated `ifconfig` or the obsolete "alias" notation (like `eth0:0`) in `/etc/network/interfaces` because in [IP Aliasing](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/alias.txt) (on www.kernel.org) you can read

> IP-aliases are an obsolete way to manage multiple IP-addresses/masks
>   per interface

Comment: ifconfig is deprecated? I didn't know.

Comment: @Mahesh Yeah, ifconfig is an artifact from the SysV era. 'iproute2' is the more modern tool. ifconfig will be around for a while on various distros, but yeah, it's deprecated; "deprecated" is just a colloquialism we used to denote "look for something newer to use".

Answer (score 57, accepted):

1. If you need an additional IP address just for the moment you can add it to any interface on your machine with

   ```
    sudo ip address add <ip-address>/<prefix-length> dev <interface>
   ```

   for instance

   ```
    sudo ip address add 172.16.100.17/24 dev eth0
   ```

   would add `172.16.100.17` using a 24 bit network prefix to the list of addresses configured for your `eth0`.

   You can check the result with

   ```
   ip address show eth0
   ```

   and you can delete this address again with

   ```
   sudo ip address del 172.16.100.17/24 dev eth0
   ```

   Of course these changes are lost when you reboot your machine.
2. To make the additional addresses permanent you can edit the file `/etc/network/interfaces` by adding as many stanzas of the form

   ```
   iface eth0 static
       address 172.16.100.17/24
   ```

   so that it looks like

   ```
   iface eth0 inet dhcp

   iface eth0 inet static
       address 172.16.100.17/24

   iface eth0 inet static
       address 172.16.24.11/24
   ```

   You can even keep the `dhcp` for the primary address.

   To activate these settings without a reboot use `ifdown/ifup` like

   ```
   sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0
   ```

   It is **essential** to put those two commands into **one** line if you are remoting into the server because the first one will drop your connection! Given in this way the ssh-session will survive.

Comment: You can maybe make an vpn whit more then one ip address by installing from from software manager.

Comment: No reboot is required on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS after adding or deleting an IP

Comment: looks like ifdown is deprecated in newer Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 22):

With the new toolkit, it is as easy as with the old to add new ip addresses:

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev eth0
```

When looking with `ip addr show` again, you see the second ip address assigned to the interface:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet 192.168.1.1/24 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::223:54ff:fe45:f307/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Remove that ip address with:

```
ip addr del 192.168.1.1/24 dev eth0
```

---

**The iproute2 suite:**

The iproute2 suite is the communication suite for interprocess communication beween the kernel and the user space via the netlink protocol. It should replace the whole standard network tools.  Here is what they replace:

- `ifconfig` --> `ip addr` and `ip link`
- `route` --> `ip route`
- `arp` --> `ip neigh`
- `iptunnel` --> `ip tunnel`
- `ipmaddr` --> `ip maddr`
- `netstat` --> `ss`

Comment: Thx for providing the matching commands.

Comment: thx @chaos, well can I have more ip's than my no of interfaces on my system??

Comment: @jazzz yes, as you can see in the output of my interface above, there are 2 ip addresses assigned to it (192.168.0.100 and 192.168.1.1). You can add another one if you wish.

Comment: @chaos, but how can I use them, for an instance I want to create a group for multicasting,,can I form a group from them,, can you please refer to my question http://askubuntu.com/questions/547105/how-to-fix-a-port-number-statically-for-client-request-on-client-side

Comment: @chaos I am accepting my own answer instead of your excellent one because yours lacks the "permanency" which I expect on a server config.

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth1
```