# add additional ipv4 addressess to the interface

Tags: 14.04

I faced a small problem when assigning multiple IPv4 addresses to the interface. I added 2 IPv4 addresses by following these steps :

- first, I added the 2 IPv4 addresses using these command-lines:

  ```
  #sudo ip address add  10.0.0.21/24 dev eth1
  #sudo ip address add  10.0.1.21/24 dev eth1
  ```

  To check the result I typed the following command-line :

  ```
  #ip address show eth0.
  ```
- Second, to make these configurations permanent, I edited the
  `/etc/network/interfaces` file by adding specific configurations and now it looks like this:

  ```
  auto eth1 
  iface eth1 inet static
         address 10.0.0.21
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         gateway 10.0.0.1

  auto eth1 
  iface eth1 inet static
         address 10.0.1.21
         netmask 255.255.255.0
         gateway 10.0.1.1
  ```
- Finally, to activate these settings without a reboot , I used the
  `ifdown/ifup` by typing:

  ```
  #sudo ifdown eth1 && sudo ifup eth1.
  ```

The first problem is when I used the ifdown/ifup command , I got this notifications:

```
ifdown: interface eth1 not configured
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth1.
```

whereas I updated the `/etc/network/interfaces` so, normally it may to recognize the interface.

The second problem is when I rebooted my machine all the setting were lost.
thank you

Comment: Why Do you want to define `eth1` properties twice?

Comment: two gateways? that will be an issue as that adds two default routes. Are you sure you know what you want?

Comment: I would like to assign 2 ipv4 addresses to eth1 because I only have one interface , there is an another solution which is using the alias (eth1:0) but I find in the INTERNET that you should assign multiple ipv4 addresses like I did and here is the link http://askubuntu.com/questions/547289/how-can-i-from-cli-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add secondary ip on interface you must create sub-interface.

In you case `eth1:1`

```
auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
       address 10.0.0.21
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 10.0.0.1

auto eth1:1 
iface eth1:1 inet static
       address 10.0.1.21
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 10.0.1.1
       metric 20
```

Based on comment I edit answer and add metric to interface `eht1:1`. This mean that gateway on `eth1` will be primary routing decision. You can add metric to `eth1` if you wish `eth1:1` be primary.

Edit 2

I found more people which have the same problem and solution is:

```
auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet static
       address 10.0.0.21
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       gateway 10.0.0.1
       up ip addr add 10.0.1.21/24 dev eth1 label eth1:1
       down ip addr del 10.0.1.21/24 dev eth1 label eth1:1
       up ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1:1 metric 20
       down ip route del 10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.1 dev eth1:1 metric 20
```

Comment: two gateways?  that will be an issue as that adds two default routes. Which one wins? ;) Oh, that's an issue in the question already... sorry

Comment: I edit answer :)

Comment: do I  have to type the ifdown/ifup command for activating the change  ?

Comment: `sudo service networking restart`

Comment: `stop: Job failed while stopping`
`start: Job is already running: networking`

Comment: the easiest is to reload pc

Comment: the ipconfig show me only eth1 so that eth1:1 were removed after rebooting

Comment: Try with `sudo ifconfig eth1:1 up`

Comment: If steal can not have success you can add secondary ip with command `sudo ifconfig eth1:1  10.0.1.21 netmask 255.255.255.0` and add route with command `sudo route add -net 10.0.1.0/24 gw 10.0.1.1 dev eth1:1 metric 20`

Comment: You have Edit 2 in my answer