# Ubuntu Networking Issue

Tags: networking

Trying to bind a /28 to my Ubuntu 14.04 dedicated server. Everything looks good, but I can't ping any IP from my server except its own .82. I'm baffled.

My resolv.conf is set to Google's DNS (I even had the primary IP first, both don't work).

My `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.42.82
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        gateway xxx.xxx.42.81
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers xxx.xxx.42.82

user@ubuntu:~$ ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:3a:c2:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.42.82/28 brd xxx.xxx.42.95 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe3a:c236/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

       user@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:3a:c2:36  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.42.82  Bcast:xxx.xxx.42.95  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe3a:c236/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1988597 errors:0 dropped:1277940 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:562121 errors:198 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:198
          collisions:16020 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:281303904 (281.3 MB)  TX bytes:121464307 (121.4 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fb5e0000-fb600000
```

Also ran `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

Tried below too, still can't ping anything except .82 primary.

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xxx.xxx.42.82
        netmask 255.255.255.240
        gateway xxx.xxx.42.81
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:3a:c2:36  
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.42.82  Bcast:xxx.xxx.42.95  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::225:90ff:fe3a:c236/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14425 errors:0 dropped:12092 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:911 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1118063 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:212166 (212.1 KB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fb5e0000-fb600000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1210 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1210 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:66658 (66.6 KB)  TX bytes:66658 (66.6 KB)
```

UPDATE FOR GUNTBERT

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo ip addr add xxx.xxx.42.80/28 dev eth0
user@ubuntu:~$ ip addr show 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:3a:c2:36 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet xxx.xxx.42.82/28 brd xxx.xxx.42.95 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet xxx.xxx.42.80/28 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fe3a:c236/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:90:3a:c2:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Based on your outputs you have to many dropped packets. Try to change port on switch or cable. Maybe you have ip .82 on two hosts?

Comment: Updated post, Still can't connect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I (from CLI) assign multiple IP addresses to one interface?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/547289/how-can-i-from-cli-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-interface)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/  You only have one IP address...

Comment: @Fabby what do you mean I have only one IP? I have a /28, it's mine. It's routed at the core switch. I see it. But, it's not pinging in the Ubuntu server, except primary .82.

Comment: @guntbert Just updated my post, tried that method too.

Comment: Ah!  Now I understand!  You're ON the server trying to ping the router! Can you see a link up in the core switch for your NIC?  Can you do a `sudo ethtool --change eth0 speed 10 duplex half autoneg off` on the server and see if that changes anything?

Comment: Leave a comment @Fabby with the reply.

Comment: @fabby, I am not trying to ping the router. I am trying to ping the IPs that are ROUTED to the server. I have a /28 routed to the server (this Ubuntu server). The problem is, none of the IPs in the /28 subnet are pinging EXTERNALLY to the server except the primary .82 one. That command you told me to run just brought down the network and screwed things up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26950/discussion-between-bashed-and-fabby).

Comment: Your router lan port is on ip `xxx.xxx.42.81` with network mask `255.255.255.240`?

Comment: @2707974 I just fixed the subnetting to .64/28 correctly. But, even after updating the network config and restarting network, still no ping.

Comment: You have my answer

Comment: Fixed it, it was the prefix but only the networking config file had to be individually set IPs like auth etho:0, auto eth0:1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xxx.xxx.xxx.64 / 28` mean host from `xxx.xxx.xxx.65` - `xxx.xxx.xxx.79`.  One address from this range must be on lan port of router.

Example

Router config for lan port

```
ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.65
nm: 255.255.255.240
```

Host config

```
ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.66
nm: 255.255.255.240
gw: xxx.xxx.xxx.65
```