# 2 ip addresses for 2 Server on 1 computer?

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, apache2

I want to create 2 ip addresses, which every single one leads to a diffrent website, I tried to do it with virtual hosts, but I couldnt configure it the way I want it to work.

I want it to look like this:

(192.168.1.41) goes  to var/www/html/sitea/hs.html

(192.168.1.46) goes to var/www/html/siteb/index.html

I tried adding an IP address , with this tutorial, and it worked fine:
[How can I (from CLI) assign multiple IP addresses to one interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547289/how-can-i-from-cli-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-interface) I can now access my diffrent serverpages on both internal IP addresses.

but I tried to forward the second IP to use it with my external IP, and now when I want to get on my page from the www, it just displays me siteb on both ports.

Comment: Telling the system what site listens where is specific to your web server software.  But you can get them to all listen on one IP which makes things easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've made it work with giving the virtual host (etc/apache2/sites-enabled) an specific IP like so:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.41:*>
..
(sitea)
..
<VirtualHost/>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.46:*>
..
(siteb)
..
<VirtualHost/>
```