# Multiple ip addresses on single nic removes dns-* options

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, 16.04

I need 2 or 3 local ip addresses on a single nic on my Ubuntu server 16.04 (on virtualbox with intel pro/1000 mt network card). Currenlty I have this:

```
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
        name            WAN
        address         10.0.2.10/24
        gateway         10.0.2.1
        broadcast       10.0.2.255
        dns-search      ubuntu.local
        dns-nameserver  127.0.0.1
        dns-nameserver  8.8.8.8

#iface enp0s3 inet static
#        name            LAN_1
#        address         10.0.2.11/24
```

and the `/etc/resolv.conf` contains:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
search ubuntu.local
```

and everything work (host is pingable and reachable). But when I uncomment those three lines and reload networking `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty. And according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/547300/82974) and [this](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface) it should be working. What I'm doing wrong ?