# Failed to bring up eth2 - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I set up an Ubuntu 16.04 server as guest in Virtualbox.
The server uses 3 interfaces in the network settings: Host-only, NAT, Bridged

The /etc/network/interfaces file is set as following:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Host-only interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.56.105
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.56.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255

# NAT interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

# Bridged interface
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
address 192.168.0.105
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.255
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

I've disabled the "Predictable Network Interface Names" option into the grub config

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0"
```

During the reboot I have this message:

```
Failed to start Raise network interfaces
```

but when I run ifconfig everything seems ok:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:37:e4:c4  
          inet addr:192.168.56.105  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe37:e4c4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:35338 (35.3 KB)  TX bytes:5530 (5.5 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:d6:8d:1a  
          inet addr:10.0.3.15  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fed6:8d1a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2970 (2.9 KB)  TX bytes:3063 (3.0 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6d:be:ad  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6d:bead/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:55125 (55.1 KB)  TX bytes:1988 (1.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)
```

However when I run

```
sudo service networking restart
```

I get this message:

```
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with 
error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" 
for details.
```

Here's the result of journalctl -xe

```
-- Unit networking.service has begun starting up.
May 07 16:31:54 jakku ifup[2056]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
May 07 16:31:54 jakku ifup[2056]: Failed to bring up eth2.
May 07 16:31:54 jakku systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 07 16:31:54 jakku systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
-- Subject: Unit networking.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit networking.service has failed.
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: According to: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13895/solving-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-when-running-ifup you can have only 1 gateway in interfaces file.

Comment: But it works on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. 
Anyway I tried to remove the gateway but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100588/using-ip-addr-instead-of-ifconfig-reports-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-on-de and http://serverfault.com/questions/403969/failed-to-bring-up-wlan0

Comment: Anything of interest in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you are falling into an old trap. According to several posts [e.g. one by codeghar](https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/debian-running-etcinit-dnetworking-restart-is-deprecated-because-it-may-not-enable-again-some-interfaces/) `sudo service networking restart` has long been deprecated

> because it may not enable again some interfaces

Jorge Castro gave [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/376586/117103)

```
sudo ifdown --exclude=lo -a && sudo ifup --exclude=lo -a
```

So replace `networking restart` with `ifdown... && ifup...`.

Just as an aside: `ifconfig` has also been deprecated for a long time - use `ip` from the package `iproute2` (also see [my question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/547289/117103))