# How to setup multiple IPs on a Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, ip

I have rented 2 subnets and got them announced on a Ubuntu 14.04 server, I have managed to setup one of the subnets perfectly fine but I am having issues with the second one. I have added them to the interfaces file but I cannot connect to the server via the new IPs and I cannot ping them either.

If anyone can tell me other methods to setup new IP addresses or is willing to help me set them up I can compensate for their time.

```
auto eth0:323

iface eth0:323 inet static
address 185.176.88.67
netmask 255.255.255.248


auto eth0:324

iface eth0:324 inet static
address 185.176.88.68
netmask 255.255.255.248
```

This is a cutout from my interfaces file.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible http://askubuntu.com/a/547300/231142

Comment: Tried the solutions listed there but none seemed to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to add gateways.  The first one that you have set is working because it's using a default gateway, so you don't neccesarily have to include the gateway in the settings.

The one that isn't working is having problems using the already default gateway.  Get the gateway for the network and add it to your configuration.

```
auto eth0:323

iface eth0:323 inet static
address 185.176.88.67
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway x.x.x.x

auto eth0:324

iface eth0:324 inet static
address 185.176.88.68
netmask 255.255.255.248
gateway x.x.x.x
```

The "**X's**" are to be replaced by the gateway provided by your ISP.