# How to increase browsing speed using multiple ips on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, browser

I am trying to increase my browsing speed but cannot find any suitable method. I have tried to use multiple ip's for increasing download speed using disptach proxy and commands provided in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547289/how-can-i-from-cli-assign-multiple-ip-addresses-to-one-interface) but it only increases my download speed not browsing speed. Any Suggestions?

Comment: This is an "XY problem". Why do you think your browser speed is "slow"? What is your hardware config? How are you connected?

Comment: Sorry can you clear what hardware configuration you want to know?