# How to set up routing between two networks?

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, windows-10, vpn, routing

How to set up routing between two networks?

Network #1
ip-10.10.10.1
mask-255.255.255.255

ip-10.10.10.2
mask-255.255.255.255

Network #2
ip-10.10.0.0
mask-255.255.255.0
gw-10.10.0.10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke6dc.png)

Comment: This resembles a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Is that how the network is physically wired? I suspect not. I would expect you to have a wifi network, or one where the nodes link to a central hub via CAT-5  cables. Or you are using a network of virtual machines.

In any case you need the nodes to understand how to cross the subnet boundary. This is normally the job of a router. Often a reasonably priced intelligent hub or broadband modem can do this by defining multiple subnets.

If it needs to be done on one node (top right on your diagram - That is helpful, well done. Extra points for explaining the config!)  then the problem can be restated as "how do I have two subnets on one interface". And that has already been answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469272/two-subnets-on-one-interface)

There will be minor changes because you will be using netplan, but you will get the idea.